# How can I increase item max size in docker ansible

Tags: docker, ansible, memcached

I run server with docker and ansible.

I want to add setting of item_max_size and slab_chunk_max

How can I do this?

here is my code.

```
- name: run memcached
  docker:
    name: memcached
    image: memcached
    state: reloaded
    pull: always
    ports:
        - "11211:11211"
    memory_limit: "2048MB"
```

Thank you.

Comment: max size of what?

Answer (score 0):

At least 50% of the ones you mentioned are supported by `memcached`'s  command-line configuration interface, as shown in [the fine manual](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/1.6.9/doc/memcached.1#L141). I'm going to **assume** you are in fact using the correct [`docker_container:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/community/general/docker_container_module.html) task, and not just making up ansible tasks, and that your indentation is merely a careless copy-paste error in your SO question

```yaml
- name: run memcached
  docker_container:
    name: memcached
    detach: yes
    image: memcached
    command:
    - memcached
    - --item-max-size=12345678
    # I didn't see this option, but feel free to try it
    # - --slab-chunk-max
  state: reloaded
```